# How to calculate the capacitor output when connected to ac of 220v?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, resistors, voltage-measurement

***Sorry*** for the incomplete question. What I meant was, I have a schematic diagram of a light sensor and drives LEDs in series, on measuring the output voltage it showed about **5v**(*if LDR is partially covered*) to an approx of 15v(*if LDR is completely covered*). I want to modify in such a way that it gives 12v DC in order to drive a relay which would further connect to an AC load.

I have attached an image of the circuit. So my question is what would be the output voltage when a capacitor(220nF) and resistor(1M) connected in parallel? How would you go about calculating the voltage? 
[image]

Comment: If connected in parallel with 220v, you just apply KVL and you have the very same 220v as before. Draw a schematic and be more clear.

Comment: Huh? What's a "224J"?

Comment: @OlinLathrop It's a \$220\:\textrm{nF}\$, I think. (Might be a youngster playing around with ceramic caps and big valued resistors across a mains line for curiosity or perhaps operating an LED in series. It's the kind of question that might ignorantly arise if playing like that.)

Comment: That's what you get for posting almost nothing about what you are doing. And yes, I tend to play it safe when there is so little written. So what exactly _are_ you doing here?

Comment: Without knowing the load it would be connected to its impossible to say exactly but something it would be between 0 and 220V. The 1M0 resistor is there to discharge any residual voltage when the circuit is switched off.

Comment: @RohanLJ You have shown that you are utterly clueless by referring to these capacitors as "224J". No one would do that if they know even the slightest what they are doing. You then go on by insulting those trying to figure out this puzzle for you. Rest assured that this disqualifies you from getting an answer.

Comment: @pipe I am so Sorry if I insulted anyone,I really never meant to insult anyone. Maybe I couldn't explain my question properly sorry.

Comment: Looks like @RohanLJ is a newbie at reverse engineering a night light bulb from the way the bridge was drawn and Cap value .. but his question is what are the Design Rules for C ratio and values in a "Cap transformer" ? in an offline low current DC load supply.

Comment: @pipe I am not 'insulted'. Cool down, mate. Read his description, probably which you didn't pay attention to - he knows 220J means 220nF. If one doesn't undergo formal Electronics education, although an enthusiast, what else other than internet forum/blog could be a better way for him to learn?
Rohan, Varying the value of 220nF cap would change the output current. Why not add a 12V 1W zener after the 20K resistor to ground and re-check? I think you see 5V, 15V etc, because of your load. Try measuring without load. And the circuit has no 'mains isolation' and would cause shock. Be careful.

Comment: @sribasu I'm not sure what you're replying to. I suggest you read his description, the _original_ one. Then read the comments posted up to then, and his reply. He has completely rewritten the question after it was closed. He has apparently also deleted his insulting reply.

Comment: @pipe Ah! Now I see, why you got so angry! :) Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Maybe? This is what it should be.**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuuFvy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R1 = safety R to discharge C1 when removed

Or is it a nite lite?

Comment: Thank you so much @Tony Stewart. EE since '75 for the relevant information. And of course for the correct schematic diagram. Yes,it is a night light Sche.Dig. I had a thought to modify in such a way that instead of lightning LEDs it should drive a 12v relay. Hmm.. Thanks.

Comment: reverse LDR and R3 position but keep same ratio for night light. It won't work unless it is a Darlington due to R3/ESR ratio >1000 for LED=~15 Ohms @75mW rating